# JCompononet Object Passed to Action Listener not updating itself with new changes

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener, pass-by-reference

```
Calling Method    
public void callingMethd(){
         jbutoon.addActionListener( new ListenToSave(p));//execute on some event
          //want to use updated p here.but the thing is after we add call listen to save,compononet //added in ListenToSave class wont reflect back here.I guess some problem with reference 

}
public class ListenToSave implements ActionListener {
    JPanel gameMatrixPanel=null;
    public ListenToSave(JPanel p){
    gameMatrixPanel=p;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           gameMatrixPanel.add(//some compononent);
    }

    }
```

The problem happening is i wanna use the updated panel p in calling method after its get update by ListenToSave().But the updation of panel is not happening in calling method.what to do

Comment: I don't think that your posted code and text is adequate to allow us to understand your problem enough to answer it. If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
new ListenToSave(p);
```

This simply invokes the constructor of ListenToSave. All the constructor does is

```
gameMatrixPanel=p;
```

So, it doesn't modify anything in the panel.

What modifies the panel is

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    gameMatrixPanel.add(//some compononent);
}
```

This method will only be called

- if the ListenToSave listener is added as the ActionListener of a button or other component
- when this button or other component is clicked or modified so that an ActionEvent is fired by the component.

Your code thus doesn't make a lot of sense, but I don't really know what your actual intention is, so it's hard to provide a solution.

For the time being, I suggest you read the [swing tutorial on events and listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html), because it seems you haven't really grasped the concept.

Comment: new ListenToSave(p);//execute on some event.... As i have mentioned that this constructor we will be called as part of some event like mouseclick .So the control will go to actionPerformed.So in short it will be like this  // jbutton.addActionListener(new ListenToSave(p));

Comment: So, the posted code is not at all the same as the real code? That doesn't help. Anyway, that doesn't change much. Adding a listener to a button adds the listener to the button. The actionPerformed() method will be called later, when the button is clicked. Adding listeners is normally done when the frame or panel is constructed. Then the user uses the panel, and when he clicks a button, its action listeners are called. You should add a listener when another listener is invoked. That doesn't make much sense.